# Could not enter Jamaica

Tags: us-citizens, denial-of-entry, jamaica

I am an American citizen with a US passport. I bought a one-way ticket to Jamaica to visit friends and my boyfriend. He is incarcerated at the moment until October 2018.

I was told that I could not visit someone who is incarcerated and I explained that I understood that but I was also there to visit other friends. They asked me where I would be staying. Who I would be staying with. How much money I had. How I met these people and had I ever met them in person.

I have known them for over 2 years but it's been online communication so I had decided that I was going to go to Jamaica to visit them and take a vacation.

They then put me in a detaining room and then guided me back on the plane and said that I could not enter their country without a return ticket. I asked if I could purchase a return ticket and they refused.

Will I be able to go to Jamaica with a round-trip ticket?

Comment: @Dhall, without knowing your citizenship, your visa or immigration or tourist status, and the reason(s) you were "deported" — that's in quotation marks because you might have withdrawn your request to enter Jamaica, a completely different legal action — we'd all be guessing.

Comment: Why were you deported? Criminal record? Lack of funds? Suspected ties to terrorism? Poor body odor? Insulting Buju Banton?

Comment: @RobertColumbia while much is omitted from this question, I think it is safe to infer that Dhall believes that the lack of a round-trip ticket was the reason for the deportation.

Comment: Note that entering as a tourist using a one-way ticket is not normally banned, but countries will want to know how you plan to leave. If you can credibly explain that you are, say, planning to meet your yacht-owning friend in Montego Bay where you will sail to Puerto Rico and enter using your US passport, that should be fine, you just need to be able to *explain* it to the skeptical immigration official, and show applicable documents.

Comment: On top of the other comments and answers, consider _why_ your boyfriend is incarcerated. If it is related to drugs, or to gang violence, the authorities may believe that your other friends that you also met online are a criminal organization of some sort. And if you do ever get there, make sure they don't salt your luggage with contraband they want you to take into the USA.

Answer (score 1):

The Consultate General of Jamaica in New York lists what is needed, which does include a round trip or return ticket:

> **[Requirements For Entry Into Jamaica](http://www.congenjamaica-ny.org/visas/requirements-2/)**
>
> All visitors are required to be in possession of a national passport or other acceptable travel document establishing nationality and identity, and bearing a photograph.  The  passport or other travel document must be valid for the period of intended stay in the island. Visitors are also required to show evidence of sufficient funds to support themselves during their stay and be in possession of a return or round trip ticket to another country to which they are admissible.

Online relationships can be considered an issue, when you have never met those individuals in person. Should that arrangement fail, your ability to finance your stay might be questioned. Additionally, visiting an inmate requires prior [application and approval](http://www.dcs.gov.jm/files/form_visitors_relatives_etc.pdf) by the Correctional authorities; had you done that?

All in all, it seems that a number of elements fell short, and you would want to take care of all of those before trying again with a round-trip ticket in hand.